# Why does the screen go black when I make the shutter speed faster?

Tags: shutter-speed

I have a Canon 600D and in manual mode, if I make the shutter speed higher, then the screen turns blackish/black; but with the same settings when I open the camera's flash it works well. In the day, the flash looks bad--that's why I can't shoot at daytime in public.

Comment: Please post a sample image (with shooting parameters - shutter speed, aperture, ISO) for both an image taken with slow shutter speed which looks good and a dark one with faster shutter speed.

Comment: Are you asking why making the shutter speed faster makes the exposure dark in manual mode? Can you explain what you *expect* to happen?

Comment: I don't quite understand the flash part. Probably you are using a faster shutter speed than the sync speed when using a flash.

Comment: @Rafael - I think he's saying the photo is (a bit) better with flash, meaning there is more light, but it wont help (much) outdoors. Hard to tell though...

Answer (score 4):

Quite simply the faster your shutter, the less light you get to the sensor.

You have 3 options:

- lower your shutter speed
- widen your aperture
- increase sensor sensitivity (ISO)

The point of manual mode is to give you COMPLETE control, but it sounds like you dont yet understand the way exposure works.

I would suggest you use P (basically full auto aperture/shutter) until you have learned a bit more

Comment: -1 for completely failing to mention ISO.

Comment: Hehe! ah yes, totally forgot about that (fighting with a server currently, added...)